# Confused about static IP address (16.04) (may be lubuntu)

Tags: networking, static-ip

Here is what my `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

However, if I use the GUI by...

- clicking on the network connection near the clock,
- clicking **Edit Connections**
- selecting the only choice in the list (in my case wired connection 1)
- picking **Edit**
- picking the **IPv4** tab

I see a static 192.168.1.96 with a netmask of 24 and a gateway of 192.168.1.2.

[image: connection info and config in screenshot]

- First off, how is it possible I have a netmask of 24? Shouldn't it be 255,255,255,0?
- Secondly, I no longer have any device at that gateway address (I did have till last week, but it is now gone) and my browser still works to get to the internet.`
- Third, where is this information stored if not in the /etc/network/interfaces` file?

Just for completeness, here are the results of ifconfig:

```
$ ifconfig
enp2s2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:d8:39:2e:13
          inet addr:192.168.1.96  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::211:d8ff:fe39:2e13/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2601:602:67f:f5c0:d0e2:7433:1cd5:d227/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2601:602:67f:f5c0:211:d8ff:fe39:2e13/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:720843 errors:0 dropped:361 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:394690 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:254038082 (254.0 MB)  TX bytes:110719667 (110.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:999968 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:999968 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:323242248 (323.2 MB)  TX bytes:323242248 (323.2 MB)
```

Comment: 1. https://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html 2. How should anyone know? 3. /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/...

Comment: @mikewhatever thanks for the link to that useful cheat sheet!

Answer (score 0):

1. Netmask /24 is the same as 255.255.255.0 by another nomenclature
2. Some one manually setup your IP address to `192.168.1.96` and the gateway to `192.168.1.2`
3. Try snooping into the directory `/etc/network/interfaces.d/*`

Comment: O.K. I will research the /24 thingy. Yes, once upon a time I did set a static address. The /etc/network/interfaces.d directory is empty.

Comment: It is now likely I won't know as I removed the static info from the GUI and I am able to set the IP via the router. Thanks for your help. @Stephen